# How I conditionally stop execution <p:dataTable>'s page event during page change

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In my application I have a `<p:dataTable>` with pagination using lazy datamodel.

I have a requirement when I click another page button from a page, a confirmation popup should generate, if I click `yes` then I can go to another page and if I click 'no' then I can't go to another page and I will stay in that current page.

.xhtml code are given below:

```
<h:form id="userListForm">
    <p:dataTable var="user" id="userTable" value="#{userListController.userDataModel}" lazy="true" paginator="true" rows="25" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100" widgetVar="userDataTable" styleClass="userTable" selectionMode="single" >
       <p:ajax event="page" />

       <p:column id="nameColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['name']}"
           sortBy="#{user.fullName}" filterBy="#{user.fullName}" styleClass="userName">
           <h:outputText value="#{user.fullName}" />
       </p:column>

       <!-- other columns -->

    <:/p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I am using primefaces 3.4, jsf 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired from RongNK's answers, you may simply do this,

add this script block :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onPageStart() {
        return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
</script>
```

and put this in your datatable :

```
<p:ajax event="page" onstart="return onPageStart()" />
```

You could also inline it in the `<p:ajax` this way :

```
<p:ajax event="page" onstart="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
```

Tested and working with PrimeFaces 3.4.2

Comment: You right, i use Primefaces 3.2, so i try that code first but not work, and it work in 3.4

Comment: thanks @ajacob: I also did same like you advice being inspired from `RongNK`, thanks again for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<p:ajax event="page" onstart="return tests()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
                var vpage = 1;
                var prevvalue = vpage;
                function tests(){
                    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
                        var p = userDataTable.getPaginator();
                        vpage = p.getCurrentPage();
                        prevvalue = vpage;
                        return true;}
                    else {
                        var p = userDataTable.getPaginator();
                        p.setPage(prevvalue,true);
                        return false;}
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, here `return true` `return false` is not working. I mean if click `yes` as well as `no` I can't cancel execution of fired `page event`.

Comment: i have just checked above code, it not work in the first click, after that work !